# How to store expandable listview data in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, expandablelistview

I am making one application in android I have expandable listview in that I have 8 group items and each group item consists two child items so that I want to save this static data in database after that dynamically I should add to either group or child element.So my problem is How many tables should I maintain for storing expandable list data.
I am thinking that One table it consists group as onecolumn and another one is arraylist of childs.so in sqlite we can't store arraylist so that I am storing in jsonstring after that I am adding to table but at the time of adding new category I have to parse jsonstring this is long procedure is there any alternative for storing data

code:

```
   categoryList.add("Home");
    categoryList.add("movies");
    categoryList.add("sports");
    categoryList.add("Department");
    categoryList.add("Entertainment");
    categoryList.add("vehicals");
    categoryList.add("Medical");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("uniqueArrays", new JSONArray(items));
String arrayList = json.toString();
```

Comment: use just one table with the structure: int _id, int parentId, string name

Comment: It depends on your preferences e.g. size of data, uses of it, etc. You can have one table in which you should have two columns parent_id and child_id to identify each parent child pair or you can have two tables parent and child. and in child table you can have one column of parent_id to identify which parent the child belongs to.